# Running graphical programs in console mode

Tags: command-line, console

I want to use Ubuntu in console mode (ctrl + alt + f1) instead of the graphical interface. Is it possible to run a graphical program, such a browser or a game from it?

Comment: You would need to do something similar to `startx` from within the tty. Think of it as it's own separate terminal.

Comment: Could you explain some more?

Comment: The ttys are basically like an emulator for a terminal (think kinda like terminal/mainframe, or a separate computer entirely). When you load up your OS, you actually have scripting which will run something to start your graphical interface. `startx` is one command which would do that depending on what you are using. But this is all done in one of your ttys (so Ctrl + Alt + `F1-F8`) you return to the original one with F1/F2 usually, but they are all basically ttys just one is running GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start an Xsession for an X program to run.
You can open an Xsession just for your program with xinit, ie to start firefox:

```
xinit /usr/bin/firefox -- :9
```

You must use a full binary path and assign a free display server (the -- :9 at the end)

A lot of modern applications may expect some kind a binding to a WM, so this may not work as well as expected.

Also, you can change the new Xsession screen resolution with xrandr.

Comment: How do I change the resolution exactly?

Comment: xrandr -s <resolution> --display <display>. You can list available resolutions with "xrandr -q"  or add you own resolution (3rd post here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1112186)

Answer (score 1):

If by running a graphical program from a shell, sure... ie on the command line enter **gedit** filename where filename is a file you want to edit.  If you have the graphical portion of Ubuntu installed it will start up.

I do not recall the name specifically off hand, but there are specific browsers that are text only that are very small format and do a pretty good job - providing that the website/developer wrote code that is W3C compliant.

Again, if you have installed the full graphical Ubuntu you can start a program from the command line (ie **firefox**)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I meant running without any desktop Environment, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

As for a browser, you can install **links2** and run it in graphical mode using

```
links2 -g www.google.com
```

[image: links2 in graphical mode]

You will need to have a framebuffer working and you will probably also want **gpm** so you can have a cursor. You can also run **mplayer** on the framebuffer, as for games you can install **bsdgames** and you will be able to play with :

```
backgammon
```

[image: backgammon]

```
worm
```

[image: worm]

```
tetris-bsd
```

[image: tetris-bsd]

You can also install **ninvaders** which is a cool game also.

[image: ninvaders]

P.S. : All the capture are taken on gnome-terminal but those programs work on the real console.